# how to evaluate lambda expression condition(FluentValidation)

Tags: lambda, fluentvalidation

First off, sorry if my title doesn't relate to my question. it has been a long day.

Basically, i wanted to know if i can write a class that takes lambda expression and evaluate its condition. IE:

```
(x=>x.property1 == 1) or x=>x.property1 < 1)
```

Ultimately, once the expression is passed to my class, I want to be able to evaluate the expression.

I'm trying to add some custom validator into FluentValidation. And my first issue was to be able to parse the lambda expression:

```
RuleFor(x=>x.Property2).RequiredIF(x=>x.Property1==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create it as extension method and use inside combination of calls:

```
return When(expression).NotEmpty()
```

In this way you shouldn't evaluate expression, method `When` will do it.